# Can I cache entities with non mapped properties in NHibernates 2nd level cache?

Tags: nhibernate, caching, active-directory, entity

Hi i have setup my SessionFactory to cache entities and queries:

```
private ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
{
    var cfg = new Configuration().Proxy(
        properties => properties.ProxyFactoryFactory<DefaultProxyFactoryFactory>()).DataBaseIntegration(
            properties =>
            {
                properties.Driver<SqlClientDriver>();
                properties.ConnectionStringName = this.namedConnection;
                properties.Dialect<MsSql2005Dialect>();
            }).AddAssembly(this.resourceAssembly).Cache(
                properties =>
                {
                    properties.UseQueryCache = true;
                    properties.Provider<SysCacheProvider>();
                    properties.DefaultExpiration = 3600;
                });
    cfg.AddMapping(this.DomainMapping);

    new SchemaUpdate(cfg).Execute(true, true);
    return cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
}
```

This is my user mapping

```
public class UserMapping : EntityMapping<Guid, User>
{
    public UserMapping()
    {
        this.Table("USERS");
        this.Property(
            x => x.CorpId,
            mapper => mapper.Column(
                c =>
                {
                    c.Name("CorporateId");
                    c.UniqueKey("UKUserCorporateId");
                    c.NotNullable(true);
                }));
        this.Set(
            x => x.Desks,
            mapper =>
            {
                mapper.Table("DESKS2USERS");
                mapper.Key(km => km.Column("UserId"));
                mapper.Inverse(false);
                mapper.Cascade(Cascade.All | Cascade.DeleteOrphans | Cascade.Remove);
            },
            rel => rel.ManyToMany(mapper => mapper.Column("DeskId")));
        this.Cache(
            mapper =>
            {
                mapper.Usage(CacheUsage.ReadWrite);
                mapper.Include(CacheInclude.All);
            });
    }
}
```

What I want to do is get a user or query some users and add information to the domain object and cache the updated object.

```
public class User : Entity<Guid>, IUser
{
    public virtual string CorpId { get; set; }

    public virtual ISet<Desk> Desks { get; set; }

    public virtual MailAddress EmailAddress { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "{0}, {1}", this.SurName, this.GivenName);
        }
    }

    public virtual string GivenName { get; set; }

    public virtual string SurName { get; set; }
}
```

something like this:

```
var users = this.session.Query<User>().Cacheable().ToList();

if (users.Any(user => user.EmailAddress == null))
{
    UserEditor.UpdateThroughActiveDirectoryData(users);
}

return this.View(new UserViewModel { Users = users.OrderBy(entity => entity.Name) });
```

or this:

```
var user = this.session.Get<User>(id);

if (user.EmailAddress == null)
{
    UserEditor.UpdateThroughActiveDirectoryData(user);
}

return this.View(user);
```

The UpdateThroughActiveDirectory methods work but are executed everytime i get data from the cache, the updated entities do not keep the additional data. Is there a way to also store this data in nhibernates 2nd level cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NHibernate doesn't cache entire entity in second level cache. It caches only the state / data from the mapped properties. You can read more about it here: http://ayende.com/blog/3112/nhibernate-and-the-second-level-cache-tips

There's an interesting discussion in comments of that post that explains this a little further:

> **Frans Bouma:**   Objects need to serializable, are they not? As we're talking about multiple appdomains.   I wonder what's more
>   efficient: relying on the cache of the db server or transporting
>   objects back/forth using serialization layers.
>
> **Ayende Rahien:**   No, they don't need that.   This is because NHibernate doesn't save the entity in the cache. Doing so would open
>   you to race conditions.   NHibernate saves the entity data alone,
>   which is usually composed of primitive data (that is what the DB can
>   store, after all).   In general, it is more efficient to hit a cache
>   server, because those are very easily scalable to high degrees, and
>   there is no I/O involved.